# 'CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name. Update transaction with Inner Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I set up a query to get to update on a table field(sql server) by concatenating other fields.

**My query**

```
UPDATE ORDER O
SET O.COD_MODEL_ORDER = CONCAT(M.COD_MODEL, '-', O.COD_ORDER)
INNER JOIN MODEL M ON M.ID_MODEL = O.ID_MODEL
WHERE ID_ORDER = 5;
```

Error:

> 'CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Where am I going wrong?
My objective is to join Model and Order.
Update Order field concatenating two other fields:

**- COD_MODEL(varchar) FROM MODEL**
**- COD_ORDER(varchar) FROM ORDER**

Comment: The `concat` function was added in SQL Server 2012, are you perhaps running an older version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Why not simply concatenate using +

```
UPDATE O
SET O.COD_MODEL_ORDER = M.COD_MODEL + '-' + O.COD_ORDER
FROM ORDER O
INNER JOIN MODEL M ON M.ID_MODEL = O.ID_MODEL
WHERE ID_ORDER = 5;
```